# UIActivityIndicatorView doesn't work on iPhone 4 with iOS4

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiactivityindicatorview, iphone-4

I noticed in one of my apps that the activity indicator doesn't seem to work on an iPhone 4.  It works fine on an old iPhone upgraded to iOS 4 just not on an iPhone 4.  Does anyone know why it isn't working?

Answer (score 2):

This code should do the job, is that correct;)?

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

...

activityIndicatorInstance.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
activityIndicatorInstance.layer.shadowRadius = 1;
activityIndicatorInstance.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
activityIndicatorInstance.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
```

Comment: What class is activityIndicatorInstance?  Because the compiler doesn't like that syntax for UIActivityIndicatorView: error: accessing unknown 'shadowColor' component of a property

Comment: Oscar: Yes, it is UIActivityIndicatorView... Did you add the import statement that is on top of my post?

Answer (score 1):

oddly it uses a transparent alpha channel on the iPhone 4. 
A solution may be to add a kind of background...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but found that if I coded it rather than using Interface Builder it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If your design allows, you can also use the UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray or attempt to add a dark shadow to the activityView's layer.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem, in iOS5 the frame size is already set. In iOS4 you need to set the frame size yourself. Hope it helps.